# What level does morgan use in conjunction with winston?

Tags: node.js, express, winston, morgan

I'm currently learning about logging in the context of nodejs. Currently my setup uses morgan as express middleware and winston as my logging. My question is what level of logging does morgan use? This is my appjs so far. I'm trying to decide how I'm going to split my logging.

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import express from "express";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";
import path from "path";
import { logger, stream } from "./utils/logger";
import es from "./esClient";

const app = express();

app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("combined", { stream }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

export default app;
```

and this is my logger file that I import

```
import winston from "winston";
import path from "path";

winston.emitErrs = true;

const logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
      level: "info",
      name: "info",
      filename: path.join(__dirname,"..","..","logs/access.log"),
      json: true,
      maxsize: 5242880, //5MB
      maxFiles: 5,
      colorize: true
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
      level: "verbose",
      name: "elasticsearch",
      filename: path.join(__dirname,"..","..","logs/elasticsearch.log"),
      json: true,
      maxsize: 5242880, //5MB
      maxFiles: 5,
      colorize: true
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
      level: "error",
      name: "error",
      filename: path.join(__dirname,"..","..","logs/errors.log"),
      json: true,
      maxsize: 5242880, //5MB
      maxFiles: 5,
      colorize: true
    }),
    new winston.transports.Console({
      colorize: true,
      level: "warning"
    })
  ]
});

const stream = {
  write: function(message, encoding){
    logger.info(message);
  }
};

export { logger, stream };
```

edit: For clarification, I dont want my http request logs to be logged into my database logs. is there a way to do this?

Comment: Morgan is solely an HTTP request logger middleware. Why would you want to separate HTTP request into different categories? I don't think morgan allows you to do that.

Comment: I think I may explained wrongly. What I want to do is seperate my logs. One logs for http requests, one log for database calls and one for errors. I want all my logs seperated so its easier to analyse the data

Comment: Got it. From your code, it looks like you still might be getting different logs for error/info/warning etc. But there won't be a log containing only warnings or info. That is because the priorities each log levels get. For example, winston gives the highest priority to "error" and the lowest to "debug". So what's gonna happen is, higher priority logs will be present in  all the lower priority logs, but not the otherwise. For example, "error" log will be present in warning/info/debug level logs, however warning will not be present in error log.

Comment: @AnkitGomkale I see. I kinda figured this as well. By the way one more question. Is logging to console a good practice in production? I saw somewhere from the express documentation that I shouldn't be using console.log because it blocks the event loop. So would the use of a console transport be bad for production?

Comment: You said it right. _console.log_ is a blocking function, more you use it, slower your code will be. Winstone solves this problem. You can try new logger - Pino. It's considered the fastest logger in the market.

Comment: @AnkitGomkale So to clarify, Winston does not block the event loop at all and I can use it to do all my logging without worry of Block the event loop?

Comment: That's right :)